# Is "thus + adverb" idiomatic?

Tags: meaning, adverbs, idiomatic-language

I see here and there that 'thus' is used before adverbs. What is the precise meaning of such usage? And is it idiomatic?

> Example: **thus + adverb + past participle**
>
> In pursuance of advice received from individuals **thus honestly
>   disposed**, a military party was employed, and during the first day on
>   which its services were used, they were found to be eminently
>   successful. ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=SBMPAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA689&lpg=PA689&dq=%22thus%20honestly%22&source=bl&ots=gy6-fKlQCk&sig=4Qs4PyhBHzPsiu-gPV_391ivJLA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiukrT3jInYAhVBXBQKHSDlAz8Q6AEIPjAF))

Answer (score 1):

It was certainly idiomatic before the end of the 19th century.

To be disposed can mean

> - feeling favourable about something
> - power to make decisions about
>     <sub>[disposed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disposed)</sub>

The meaning of your sentence

> On advice from individuals who honestly believed it was a good idea and had the power to decide, a military party was employed...

---

As for ***Thus*** - it is going out of fashion and not used much, likely due to it sounding old-fashioned or pompous.

I believe that *hence* is next to go.

***So***, and ***therefore*** are more modern sounding alternatives to ***thus*** and ***hence***

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing the sentence slightly incorrectly.  It isn't really "thus + adverb", it's "thus + verb-phrase", and the adverb is just modifying the verb phrase.

For example, you can say "**thus completed**, the report was sent" or "**thus finally completed**, the report was sent", but just "thus finally" doesn't make sense by itself.

In your original sentence, you could say the people were **thus disposed**, and **honestly** indicates the *way* in which they were disposed, but the people weren't "thus honestly".

It is idiomatic but somewhat old-fashioned to use *thus*.  It means something like "in this or that manner or way; to this degree or extent".